# How to create a ramdisk during a systemd service initialization (ex. Postgresql)?

Tags: systemd, postgresql, ramdisk

Is there any way to create a ramdisk during systemd service initialization and run some command after its creation and after the "main" service process starts?

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is to when starting a Postgres database (ex. `sudo systemctl start postgresql@13-my_db`) I first create a ramdisk, run a script that reads the TLS certificates and private key from a secure vault, and stores it inside that ramdisk with correct permissions, and then Postgres can start reading the files from that ramdisk.

Also, when the service is stopped, the files would go away too since the ramdisk would be automatically unmounted by systems.

Is this possible? The only way I found that almost work was to use `TemporaryFileSystem` feature to create the ramdisk and then use `ExecStartPre` to run my script that fetches the files.

This would work, but unfortunately seems like systemd unmount the ramdisk between `ExecStartPre` and `ExecStart` calls, so when the Postgres database is started, the ramdisk is already unavailable.